# Any way to see Google Play Music All Access Radio history?

Tags: google-play-music

How can I see my All Access Radio play history? There are several songs I heard last night that I wish to purchase, but I don't know the artist/track names!

Comment: When searching for this I noticed the phrases "listening history" used in google play music support pages, and "play count" used in the web interface. I'm just mentioning this hoping it will attract more search hits to the question.

Answer (score 3):

While Google does store this data it's not easily accessible to regular users and they only display what Station or Album you were listening to not the songs on that list (Under /Recent).

While this doesn't help the current situation I would recommend checking out Daniel Slaughter's [Google Play with Last.fm project](http://www.danielslaughter.com/projects/google-music-with-lastfm/) which via script allows you to Scrobble what you are playing to Last.fm.  While it's not a perfect solution (and it does have some issues) if this is something you want to use it is better than nothing until Google implements a solution.